# How can I share an object between a Rails instance and a Sidekiq instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I have a listener (using the [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) gem) object that I'm adding to a constant within an initializer:

```
LISTENER = Listen.to(REPORT, ERROR, SENT) do |modified, added, removed|
  listener.ignore! /\.swp/
  listener.ignore /\.DS_Store/
  Communicator.notify(added)
end
```

I put a little admin interface around this functionality, and I display the status of the listener in the view.

In my deployment, I have a Utility instance where all my background jobs run. I may have 1 or many app servers spinning at one time, so I only want this listener to listen on the Utility instance. Sidekiq is my background processor. Therefore, in my admin interface I enlist a simple Sidekiq worker to spin up this listener.

When I obtain the status of the listener, it says it isn't running. But the process is there. This of course is because the App server is attempting to get the listener status from the constant on the application server!

How can I get the status of the object on the Sidekiq server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 4.2 has implemented [GlobalID](https://github.com/rails/globalid) and [here](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-integrate-sidekiq-with-activejob/) is a good blog post outlining ActiveJob and it covers using GlobalID. (You can parse live object! OMG section)

I know this is an old post but I just came across it and thought this answer might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq and Application Servers do no share memory. Even the Application server instances do not share memory. You will have to use database to share the information between sidekiq and your application.

Add the status of the listener to the database from your sidekiq process. Read the database value in your application server request.

Comment: I thought about this. I'm trying to avoid the database for this one little thing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want to use Distributed Ruby: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html.

> dRuby allows methods to be called in one Ruby process upon a Ruby object located in another Ruby process, even on another machine. References to objects can be passed between processes. Method arguments and return values are dumped and loaded in marshalled format. All of this is done transparently to both the caller of the remote method and the object that it is called upon.

Comment: Although that sounds like it will work, it sounds like overkill for this one thing I want to do. There should be some way to leverage the existing ```Redis``` configuration to share that object. I have to figure out how to serialize and deserialize a Ruby object to the Redis store.